# google maps v3 only render map if resize the browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js

I have an application and in this application I have a map, but if I load the application the map is loaded like this:

[image: the problem]

The app is developed with Vuejs an Laravel and the map is loaded via vue component inside of other compoinent according the code below:

```
    <template>
   <div class="google-map">
      <div :id="mapName" style="height: 100%"></div>
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    .google-map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: gray;
    }

    /*body, html #map-canvas {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
    }*/
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'google-map',
        props: ['name'],
        data() {
            return {
                mapName: this.name + "-map",
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.initMap();
        },

        methods: {

            initMap() {
                const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
                const options = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.501527,-0.1921837)
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the component where it is loaded, I use this code:

```
<google-map name="example"></google-map>
```

I've already tried all possible solutions and did not get the expected result that the map is loaded without having to resize the browser window. Can you solve this?

Comment: why you have not body and html ?

Comment: because the content is injected for vuejs on the html. the curious thing is that if I do the google implementation with an html and use an iframe it works but I need it to work without the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Can you try triggering a `resize` event programmatically just after you create the Google Maps object?

You should do the following just after the `var map = ...`:

```js
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

You might also want to have a look at a vuejs plugin that helps you use Google Maps with vuejs, like the following: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps

I never used it personally but it might help.

Comment: I've tried this several times not even the plugin could solve my problem

Comment: Can you try to call the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` in a `setTimeout` callback with the timeout set to 0? Sometimes it is just a timing issue when the Google Maps object is not "correctly" created when the trigger method is called.

Comment: the problem should be the vue, because I use .vue files, but I tested the implementation using a php file and it worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of searching I found a JQuery plugin called gmaps and testing it I ended up finding the solution. As the map is in a form that is in a tab the solution I found was the following:

```
mounted() {
            this.initMap();
        },

initMap() {

                $('#imoveis-add-tab').on('click', function () {
                    var map = new GMaps({
                        el: '#map',
                        lat: 10,
                        lng: 10,
                        zoom: 8,
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '600px'
                    });
                });
            },
```

Thanks to all who helped me.